What is wrong with my OpAmp Circuit Calculation?
The Question:

My Workings:

My Mathematica Output:

I am attempting to solve this problem using KCL, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? My mathematica code is not outputting anything. Thank you

The condition I5 + I4 = 0 is wrong. You forgot that current can flow into the ground that's also connected to this node when you applied KCL to V4.

Thank you so much, that was it. I can't believe I was stuck at that for so long.
